# How to execute a SQL query for a range of items?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

My database has a main table (ex. `Table_A`). Column 1 contains the name of items and column 6 is date of my data row. Column 7 is type of items of column 1 which are from A to z.

For example (some rows of `Table_A`):

```
|item_1  |200  |120  |300  |40   |201702  |type_A  |
|item_2  |210  |320  |340  |10   |201702  |type_A  |
|item_1  |150  |30   |70   |38   |201703  |type_A  |
|item_2  |315  |220  |120  |40   |201703  |type_A  |
|item_3  |40   |500  |110  |35   |201702  |type_B  |
|item_4  |758  |78   |152  |61   |201702  |type_B  |
|item_3  |778  |920  |12   |330  |201703  |type_B  |
|item_4  |315  |220  |120  |40   |201703  |type_B  |
```

I want to show items from every type in column 7 from a specific date (ex.201703) and then below that sum of column 2, sum of column 3, sum of column 4, sum of column 5. and then below that rate of growth which calculate within function (((sum of month / sum of previous month)*100)-100)

For the above example, the result I expect is this:

```
|item_1  |150  |30   |70   |38   |201703  |type_A  |
|item_2  |315  |220  |120  |40   |201703  |type_A  |
|sum     |465  |250  |190  |78   |201703  |type_A  |
|rate    |13.1 |-43.1|-74.3|56   |201703  |type_A  |
|item_3  |778  |920  |12   |330  |201703  |type_B  |
|item_4  |315  |220  |120  |40   |201703  |type_B  |
|sum     |1093 |1140 |132  |370  |201703  |type_B  |
|rate    |36.96|97.23|-18.5|285.4|201703  |type_B  |
```

I have tried this code:

```
(
    SELECT  
        col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7
    FROM    
        Table_A 
    INNER JOIN 
        Table_B ON Table_A.col1 = Table_B.col1
    WHERE   
        Table_A.col6 = 201703 AND (Table_A.col7 = 'type_A')
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT  
        'sum', SUM(col2), SUM(col3), SUM(col4), SUM(col5), 201703, 'type_A'
    FROM
        Table_A 
    INNER JOIN 
        Table_B ON Table_A.col1 = Table_B.col1
    WHERE   
        Table_A.col6 = 201703 AND (Table_A.col7 = 'type_A')
) --sum of data with 'g'
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT 
        N'Rate',
        (ROUND(((((SELECT CONVERT (FLOAT, SUM(col2))
                   FROM Table_A 
                   WHERE Table_A.col6 = 201703 AND (Table_A.col7 = 'type_A')
                  ) /
                  (SELECT CONVERT (FLOAT, SUM(col2))
                   FROM Table_A 
                   WHERE Table_A.col6 = (201703 - 1) AND (Table_A.col7 = 'type_A')
                  )
                 ) * 100
                ) - 100), 2)),
        (ROUND(((((SELECT CONVERT (FLOAT, SUM(col3))
                   FROM Table_A 
                   WHERE Table_A.col6 = 201703 AND (Table_A.col7 = 'type_A')
                  ) /
                  (SELECT CONVERT (FLOAT, SUM(col3))
                   FROM Table_A 
                   WHERE Table_A.col6 = (201703 - 1) AND (Table_A.col7 = 'type_A')
                  )
                 ) * 100
                ) - 100), 2)),
        (ROUND(((((SELECT CONVERT (FLOAT, SUM(col4))
                   FROM Table_A 
                   WHERE Table_A.col6 = 201703 AND (Table_A.col7 = 'type_A')
                  ) /
                  (SELECT CONVERT (FLOAT, SUM(col4))
                   FROM Table_A 
                   WHERE Table_A.col6 = (201703 - 1) AND (Table_A.col7 = 'type_A')
                  )
                 ) * 100
                ) - 100), 2)),
        (ROUND(((((SELECT CONVERT (FLOAT, SUM(col5))
                   FROM Table_A 
                   WHERE Table_A.col6 = 201703 AND (Table_A.col7 = 'type_A')
                  ) /
                  (SELECT CONVERT (FLOAT, SUM(col5))
                   FROM Table_A 
                   WHERE Table_A.col6 = (201703 - 1) AND (Table_A.col7 = 'type_A')
                  )
                 ) * 100
                ) - 100), 2)),
        NULL,
        'type_A'
)
```

but this code shows only one type from column 7

Comment: its very easy to get this kind of result by using --->> "group by .... with rollup " in sql server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well.. i think this is what you are trying to do but i am not sure.. there are bits you will need to tweak (like i am not sure how those dates are stored - i am guessing text?):

```
select 
    item
    ,co11
    ,col2
    ,col3
    ,col4
    ,date
    ,type
from 
    table_a

union

select 
    "sum" as item
    ,sum(col1) as sc1
    ,sum(col2) as sc2
    ,sum(col3) as sc3
    ,sum(col4) as sc4
    ,date
    ,type
from 
    table_a
group by
    type
    ,date

union

select 
    "rate" as item
    ,round(((c.sc1-p.sc1)*100)-100,2)
    ,round(((c.sc2-p.sc2)*100)-100,2)
    ,round(((c.sc3-p.sc3)*100)-100,2)
    ,round(((c.sc4-p.sc4)*100)-100,2)
    ,date
    ,type
from 
    (
        select 
            ,sum(col1) as sc1
            ,sum(col2) as sc2
            ,sum(col3) as sc3
            ,sum(col4) as sc4
            ,date
            ,type
        from 
            table_a
        group by
            type
            ,date
    ) as c
    left outer join (
        select 
            ,sum(col1) as sc1
            ,sum(col2) as sc2
            ,sum(col3) as sc3
            ,sum(col4) as sc4
            ,date
            ,type
        from 
            table_a
        group by
            type
            ,date
    ) as p
        on c.type = p.type
        and (1,cast(c.date as int)) = (1,cast(p.date as int))+1
```

Also it is a bit weird to do this in the DB.. it would normally be easier to do with with two or three queries and put the data together elsewhere - especially as you have different things in each column and you will probably have to wrap the whole thing in another selection to get the ordering that would make this work:

```
select 
    item
    ,co11
    ,col2
    ,col3
    ,col4
    ,date
    ,type
from(   
    select 
        item
        ,co11
        ,col2
        ,col3
        ,col4
        ,date
        ,type
        ,0 as sortSeq
    from 
        table_a

    union

    select 
        "sum" as item
        ,sum(col1) as sc1
        ,sum(col2) as sc2
        ,sum(col3) as sc3
        ,sum(col4) as sc4
        ,date
        ,type
        ,1 as sortSeq
    from 
        table_a
    group by
        type
        ,date

    union

    select 
        "rate" as item
        ,round(((c.sc1-p.sc1)*100)-100,2)
        ,round(((c.sc2-p.sc2)*100)-100,2)
        ,round(((c.sc3-p.sc3)*100)-100,2)
        ,round(((c.sc4-p.sc4)*100)-100,2)
        ,date
        ,type
        ,3 as sortSeq
    from 
        (
            select 
                ,sum(col1) as sc1
                ,sum(col2) as sc2
                ,sum(col3) as sc3
                ,sum(col4) as sc4
                ,date
                ,type
            from 
                table_a
            group by
                type
                ,date
        ) as c
        left outer join (
            select 
                ,sum(col1) as sc1
                ,sum(col2) as sc2
                ,sum(col3) as sc3
                ,sum(col4) as sc4
                ,date
                ,type
            from 
                table_a
            group by
                type
                ,date
        ) as p
            on c.type = p.type
            and (1,cast(c.date as int)) = (1,cast(p.date as int))+1
) as a
order by
    date
    ,type
    ,sortSeq
    ,item
```

Answer (score 0):

This is full working example. You can just add some ordering if you need:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [col1] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[col2] INT
   ,[col3] INT
   ,[col4] INT
   ,[col5] INT
   ,[col6] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[col7] VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5], [col6], [col7])
VALUES ('item_1', 200, 120, 300, 40 , 201702, 'type_A')
      ,('item_2', 210, 320, 340, 10 , 201702, 'type_A')
      ,('item_1', 150, 30 , 70 , 38 , 201703, 'type_A')
      ,('item_2', 315, 220, 120, 40 , 201703, 'type_A')
      ,('item_3', 40 , 500, 110, 35 , 201702, 'type_B')
      ,('item_4', 758, 78 , 152, 61 , 201702, 'type_B')
      ,('item_3', 778, 920, 12 , 330, 201703, 'type_B')
      ,('item_4', 315, 220, 120, 40 , 201703, 'type_B');

DECLARE @curr_month VARCHAR(12) = '201703'
       ,@prev_month VARCHAR(12) = '201702';

SELECT ISNULL([col1], 'sum')
      ,SUM([col2])
      ,SUM([col3])
      ,SUM([col4])
      ,SUM([col5])
      ,[col6]
      ,[col7]
FROM @DataSource
WHERE [col6] = @curr_month
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS
(
     ([col1], [col6], [col7])
    ,([col6], [col7])
)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Rate'
      ,CAST((SUM(IIF([col6] = @curr_month, [col2], 0.0)) / SUM(IIF([col6] = @prev_month, [col2], 0.0)) * 100) - 100 AS DECIMAL(9,2))
      ,CAST((SUM(IIF([col6] = @curr_month, [col3], 0.0)) / SUM(IIF([col6] = @prev_month, [col3], 0.0)) * 100) - 100 AS DECIMAL(9,2))
      ,CAST((SUM(IIF([col6] = @curr_month, [col4], 0.0)) / SUM(IIF([col6] = @prev_month, [col4], 0.0)) * 100) - 100 AS DECIMAL(9,2))
      ,CAST((SUM(IIF([col6] = @curr_month, [col5], 0.0)) / SUM(IIF([col6] = @prev_month, [col5], 0.0)) * 100) - 100 AS DECIMAL(9,2))
      ,@curr_month
      ,[col7]
FROM @DataSource 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @DataSource DS WHERE DS.[col1] = [col1] AND [col6] = @curr_month)
GROUP BY [col7];
```

[image]

You can play around with the `DECIMAL` casting, too - currently, I am casting to `DECIMAL(9,2)` but you can change the query to match your needs.

Also, note I have added to variables to hold the current and the previous month. They can be populated with SQL, too but I hard-coded them.